# plot amount of classes that happens on certain dates graph empty

Tags: python, pandas, plot

My problem statement is this: I need to do time series forecasting where the algorithm takes a dataset that includes date, classes and the number of times a class appears each day

input data:

| date | class_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | A | 13 |
| 2021-09-01 | B | 2 |
| 2021-09-02 | A | 1 |
| 2021-09-02 | C | 7 |
| 2021-09-04 | A | 5 |

my full code is

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount = True)

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['timedate'], index_col='timedate')
class_id = data['class_id']
data['date'] = data.index.date

class_id = data['class_id']
timedate = data.index.to_series()
m1 = class_id.ne(class_id.shift())
m2 = timedate.dt.date.ne(timedate.dt.date.shift())
data['count'] = data.groupby((m1 | m2).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values

out = data.groupby(['date', 'class_id'])['count'].max().reset_index()

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

plt.ylabel('Amount of classes')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

out.index = pd.to_datetime(out['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
out.groupby('class_id').plot()
plt.plot(out.index, out['count'], )
```

[image: output]

the problem is im pretty sure this first graph is used to do training later as it seems that the testing graph is missing from the plot, but there are also multiple graphs in the output and I don't know if I should use any of them and how I could use them to predict the amount of classes in the future.

[image: plot 1]
[image: plot 2]